# Plot for predicted probabilities after blogit command

Tags: graph, stata, logistic-regression

I am looking for a way to plot the predicted probabilities of a binary outcome after estimating a logit model for grouped data using the blogit command in Stata.
The plot needs to show the predicted probability on the y axis and a continuous variable (days) on the x-axis.

I have tried the xi3 and postgr3 command from UC LA but they do not seem to work with the blogit command.

Help is really appreciated! Please let me know if you need further information.

Thanks!

Comment: `help blogit` links to `help glogit_postestimation`, which itself links to `margins` and `marginsplot`. See also [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/margins_graph12.htm) and [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/dae/predictive_margins.htm).

Comment: I tried the margins command but I am surprised by seeing the number of observations that are then being used to calculate the margins. As I am using grouped data there seems to be an issue. The number of observations used in the margins command is far below the actual number of observations.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, one simple solution would be to make a counterfactual data set where the `pop_var` is 1, and then simply use the `predict` command to get the probabilities, like the following:

```
webuse xmpl2
blogit deaths pop agecat exposed
replace pop = 1
predict probability
```

You could then graph this using various `twoway` commands, however you want. Although my example doesn't have a continuous x-axis, it could be something like:

```
twoway scatter probability agecat, by(exposed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also fit this type of model in the glm framework like this:

```
webuse xmpl2, clear
list, clean noobs
blogit deaths pop agecat exposed
glm deaths agecat exposed, link(logit) family(binomial pop) nolog
replace pop = 1
margins, at(agecat = (0 1)) 
marginsplot
```

Comment: Why would you replace the population var = 1? Wouldn't I lose a lot of information regarding how often a certain case took place?

Comment: You certainly don't have to do it. If you don't, the predicted deaths will be a function of population (6 or 21 deaths in expectation), and not probabilities.  Setting the population to 1 turns it into a probability.